# j.Query.inArray not working with external list but working with normala array

Tags: html, jquery

I am working on a website that only allow sign up from business email so i have to check if the entered email is a free email and restrict registration.

My problem is when i enter the domains manually in my array, everything works fine but when i load the domains from a txt file in to the array, it doesn't work.

Please can anybody help. I have tried everything including reducing the domains in the list but still nothing works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var blocked = new Array;
      $.get("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cokeboyyy/blackout@main/blocked.txt", function (data) {
        var blocked = data.split("\n");
        console.log(blocked);
      });

      $("button").click(function () {
        var domain = $("input").val();
        if (jQuery.inArray(domain, blocked) !== -1) {
          $("#check").html("available");
        } else {
          $("#check").html("not available");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What are the contents of that txt file?

Comment: it's a list of free hosting providers

Comment: everything loads properly when i check the console but when i try to use the in.Array function, it doesn't work. That is where i am having issues.

Comment: See if there is any JavaScript error(s) logging to the browser's console.

Comment: I have checked the console several times but there are no errors and that is why it is frustrating. no errors, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the `var` in get function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var blocked = new Array;
  $.get("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cokeboyyy/blackout@main/blocked.txt", function(data) {
    blocked = data.split("\n");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    var domain = $("input").val();
    if (jQuery.inArray(domain, blocked) !== -1) {
      $("#check").html("available");
    } else {
      $("#check").html("not available");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button>check</button>
<div id="check"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Shuo. I can't believe i spent hours trying to fix this.